# VB.Net Regular Expression, get words which may contain single quotes, that are between single quotes

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a list of countries, each country name is between single quotes, like so

```
'United States'
```

I am using this Regular Expression to match them:  `'(.*?)'`

Works great, until I get to a more obscure country name like `'Cote d'Ivoire'`, it ends up matching Cote d

How can I change my current regular expression to properly match country names such as the one I just gave as an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to force the regex engine to match the final `'` at a non-word boundary position:

```
'(.*?)'\B
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t2f9Xc/1)

You may match the first `'` when it is preceded with a non-word boundary and followed with a word boundary and similarly match the closing `'`:

```
\B'\b(.*?)\b'\B
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kdjCB5/1)

Comment: Note that in .NET regex, `\b` are Unicode-aware, so even if there is a `ł` at the end of the country name, `\b` and `\B` will identify the (non)word boundary.